# A perl command line that prints the perl version it is using to run your script

Tags: perl

I'd like to know if someone knows a function or command that I can put at the beginning of my Perl script that tells the user for example "this script is being run by perl v 5.XXX".
Specially when we have many versions installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$^V` shows the "...revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter."  From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5EV).

Answer (score 11):

You can use a special variable `$]`:

```
$ perl -e 'print $];'
5.014002
```

Comment: thank you! but a one liner with $^V is better as it shows v5.18.1. But it is always good to know!

Comment: Can 1 up this with `perl -e 'print substr($^V, 1)'`, removes the `v`